# Python regular Expression understanding

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am new to python and I am solving a problem. Can anybody tell the proper meaning if the following line of code :

```
if collections.Counter(re.findall(r"[\w']+", decrypted))[repeat] >= 2:
            return decrypted
```

decrypted is a long string and repeat is a word in that string.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's:

```
decrypted = "foo bar baz"
```

Then

```
re.findall(r"[\w']+", decrypted)
```

returns `list` of substrings of `decrypted` matches the rule `r"[\w']+"` or *all strings with letters, numbers or single quote symbol*. Result is `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`.

Method [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) create a special `dict` like object from list. Operator `[x]` of this object returns count of `x` in given list.

Finally:

```
collections.Counter(re.findall(r"[\w']+", decrypted))[repeat]
```

returns count of `repeat` sublines in `decrypted`.

Answer (score 0):

`\w` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) **meaning** all letters and number and underscores

`+` means 1 or more times (but at least 1)

You try to `findall` (global)

[**online explaination**](https://regex101.com/r/IhV8MZ/1)